# Run Azure Log Analytics query against Application Insights instances

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I'm using the Azure Log Analytics .NET SDK to execute queries.
The NuGet package I'm using for this SDK is [Microsoft.Azure.OperationalInsights](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.OperationalInsights/%5C).

Querying against a normal Workspace is fine.

Now I want to query against an Application Insights resource, like you can do in the portal via the 'Analytics' button on an Application Insights blade. For this I need a WorkspaceId, that I cannot find on the resource.

Is there a way to run these queries via the OperationalInsights SDK or do I need to create my own wrapper around the [Application Insights API](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/postQuery)? That seems to add extra authentication via the token, which I'd rather not need (I already have access to Log Analytics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that you can query across workspaces and even across apps.

For apps, use app(appName) like so:

```
app('AppInsightsName').requests
```

For a different workspace, use this:

```
workspace("workspaceId").request
```

Comment: Dude!! This is **extremely** useful information! Thank you. [Docs for ref.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/cross-workspace-query)